# LDAP Protocol and Connection in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, active-directory, ldap, electron, ldapjs

I am currently trying to build a proof of concept build of an LDAP connector in electron/Reactjs. My two main goals of building this connector are to be able to check if the user enters the correct credentials and LDAP address then they get a connection successful message. My second goal is to be able to make a group filter on change, so for example, if a user starts typing in a group name it will try to autofill/show groups that have that prefix/name. I have looked into two npm packages (LDAPjs & LDAPauth) but I am not sure if those packages would meet my needs as I am not trying to do any user authentication. Any tips or guidance on where to start on this are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You can try the [activedirectory2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/activedirectory2) package. It's a wrapper around ldapjs. AD has some quirks that other LDAP directories don't, so it handles some of those quirks for you. You can use its [`findGroups()`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/activedirectory2#findgroupsopts-callback) function to look for groups by a partial name. For example:

```
var opts = {
    filter: "cn=*admin*",
    sizeLimit: 20
}
ad.findGroups(opts, function(err, groups) {
    //do stuff with groups
}
```

That would look for the first 20 groups with "admin" in the name. Just note that making a "contains" type search like this makes it impossible for AD to use any indexes, so it has to look at *every* group on the domain to find a match. If possible, it's better to make a "starts with" type search like `"cn=admin*"`, which will complete much faster.

If these groups are distributions lists, you may want to search by `displayName` instead (`"displayName=admin*"`). Most environments set the `displayName` the same as the name of the object (`cn`), but that may not be the case for your environment. For distribution lists, the `displayName` is what is displayed to users in, say, Outlook.

You can tweak the `sizeLimit` to whatever you want to display. If the user enters only 2 or 3 characters, there's a good chance it'll match to a ton of groups, and it won't serve any useful purpose showing them all on the screen. So use this to limit the results to something manageable.

Comment: I tried implementing activedirectory2 in my project but got this error any thoughts?
client.js:1039 Uncaught TypeError: net.connect is not a function
    at connectSocket (client.js:1039)
    at Backoff.<anonymous> (client.js:1203)
    at Backoff.emit (events.js:152)
    at Backoff.push../node_modules/backoff/lib/backoff.js.Backoff.onBackoff_ (backoff.js:53)

Comment: @AustinS That depends what your code is. You're better off creating a new question for that, showing your code.

Comment: I created a new question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61961896/using-activedirectory2-package-in-electron-react-application